# Using inline SELECT with IN operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I want to select from one table based on who run the `SP`. For example if executer has `Management` role the they can see all records but if executer is `Employee` then they just see records for all employees. There are some roles like `Seller`, `StockKeeper` , ... .

Please consider this sudo code, I want to write a code like this but I got error:

```
Declare @Role      varchar(30)

select * 
from MyTable 
where Status in (IIF(@Role = 'Employee', select -1 , select -1, 0, 1))

OR

select * 
from MyTable 
where Status in (case @Role when 'Employee' then select -1 else select -1, 0 , 1 end)
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'.

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Is there any way to combine inline `SELECT` and  `IN` operator?

Thanks

---

**Edit 1)**

Sample Data:

```
Id       Value        Status
----------------------------
1         10            -1
2         20            0
3         30            -1
4         40            1
5         50            -1
6         60            0
7         70            1
8         80            -1
```

for `Employee` I want to get this result:

```
Id       Value        Status
----------------------------
1         10            -1
3         30            -1
5         50            -1
8         80            -1
```

for `Manager` I want to get All records.

Comment: If you got an error please post it with your question.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: You might want to check out some tutorials on sub-queries and other T-SQL basics. Sub-queries always require brackets. Case is an expression, not a statement, so can only return a value, not a conditional set etc

Comment: @DaleK: I know sub queries but I want to know if there is a better choice for my situation. above code is **Sudo**

Comment: You should still make your best effort to get the syntax correct... because it indicates to those answering you skill level with SQL and what help you need.

Comment: @Arian how did you get on?

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION` to build the full list of allowable statuses in a conditional manner:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE [Status] IN (
  -- Everyone gets this role
  SELECT -1
  UNION ALL
  -- Only special people get this role
  SELECT 0
  WHERE @Role <> 'Employee'
  -- Only special people get this role
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1
  WHERE @Role <> 'Employee'
);
```

Assuming your sample data is reflective of the bigger picture you could simplify that down to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
-- Everyone gets this status
WHERE [Status] = -1
-- Only special people get these statuses
OR (@Role <> 'Employee' AND [Status] IN (0, 1);
```

Notes:

- [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is an expression i.e. returns a scalar value. Its not a switch statement.
- Sub-queries require brackets around them, so even if `case` allowed it you would still need `(select -1)` rather than `select -1`.

Comment: Thanks but there is a problem: `All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can try to use conditions to judge your expected result.

if your input `@Role` is `Manager` get all data, otherwise `Employee` will get `-1`

```
Declare @Role varchar(30)

SELECT *
FROM MyTable 
WHERE (@Role = 'Employee' AND Status = -1)
OR (@Role = 'Manager')
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=eb3acedb03280e0bfecc3340a64582b0)